# Calculator with batches of operations in java

Tags: java, string, constructor, calculator

Need to do a java calculator which works with batches. It must take an operation and then, for the  next ones, just use the result of the previous operation as the first value of its new operation.

```
    public class Calculator {
/**
* Public constructor of the calculator.
*/

    **public Calculator () {/*...*/}**
 
/**
* Clean the internal state of the calculator
*/

    **public void cleanOperations () { /*...*/ }**

/**
* Add a new operation to the internal state of the calculator.
* It is worth mentioning that the calculator behaves in an accumulative way ,
* thus only first operation has two operands.
* The rest of computations work with the accumulated value and only an extra
* new operand. Second input value must be ignored if the operation does not
* correspond to the first one.
*
* @param operation operation to add , as string , "+", "-", "*", "/".
* @param values Operands of the new operation (one or two operands ).
* Uses the varargs feature.
* https :// docs.oracle.com/javase /8/ docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html
* @throws IllegalArgumentException If the operation does not exist.
*/

    **public void addOperation(String operation , float ... values) { /*...*/ }**
/**

* Execute the set of operations of the internal state of the calculator.
* Once execution is finished , internal state (operands and operations)
* is restored (EVEN if exception occurs ).
* This calculator works with "Batches" of operations.
* @return result of the execution
* @throws ArithmeticException If the operation returns an invalid value
* (division by zero)
*/

    **public float executeOperations () { /*...*/ }**

/**
* Current internal state of calculator is printed
* FORMAT:
* "[{+/ -/"/"/*}] value1_value2 [{+/ -/"/"/*}] value1 [{+/ -/"/"/*}] value1 {...}"
* @return String of the internal state of the calculator
*/
@Override
public String toString () { /* ... */ }
}
```

SOME TEST IT SHOULD PASS:

```
// Add operations, calculate internal state representation (string pattern) and execute them as a single batch
    calculator.addOperation("+", 4.5f, 6.8f);
    calculator.addOperation("-", 3.1f);
    calculator.addOperation("/", 6f);
    assertEquals("[STATE:[+]4.5_6.8[-]3.1[/]6.0]", calculator.toString());
    result = calculator.executeOperations();
    assertEquals("[STATE:]", calculator.toString()); // state is restored
    assertEquals(1.366f, result, EPSILON);//EPSILON = 0.01f
```

As you can see it must work by doing the first operation with 2 values but the next ones using the value stores from the one before and then execute with the operator and the value, the new operation.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this?

```
public class Calculator {

    private String operation;
    private float[] values;
    private float answer;

    /**
     * Public constructor of the calculator.
     */
    public Calculator() {

    }

    /**
     * Clean the internal state of the calculator
     */
    public void cleanOperations() {
         operation = null;
         values = null;
         answer = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Add a new operation to the internal state of the calculator.
     * It is worth mentioning that the calculator behaves in an accumulative way ,
     * thus only first operation has two operands.
     * The rest of computations work with the accumulated value and only an extra
     * new operand. Second input value must be ignored if the operation does not
     * correspond to the first one.
     *
     * @param operation operation to add , as string , "+", "-", "*", "/".
     * @param values    Operands of the new operation (one or two operands ).
     *                  Uses the varargs feature.
     *                  https :// docs.oracle.com/javase /8/ docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the operation does not exist.
     */
    public void addOperation(String operation, float... values) {
        if (!(operation.equals("+") || operation.equals("-") || operation.equals("*") || operation.equals("/"))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(operation + " is not a valid operator. ( '+', '-', '*', '/')");
        }
        this.operation = operation;
        this.values = values;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the set of operations of the internal state of the calculator.
     * Once execution is finished , internal state (operands and operations)
     * is restored (EVEN if exception occurs ).
     * This calculator works with "Batches" of operations.
     *
     * @return result of the execution
     * @throws ArithmeticException If the operation returns an invalid value
     *                             (division by zero)
     */
    public float executeOperations() {
        switch (operation) {
            case "+":
                if (values.length == 1) {
                    answer += values[0];
                } else {
                    for (float value : values) {
                        answer += value;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "-":
                if (values.length == 1) {
                    answer -= values[0];
                } else if (values.length != 0) {
                    answer = values[0];
                    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
                        answer -= values[i];
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "*":
                if (values.length == 1) {
                    answer *= values[0];
                } else if (values.length != 0) {
                    answer = values[0];
                    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
                        answer *= values[i];
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "/":
                if (values.length == 1) {
                    if (values[0] == 0) {
                        throw new ArithmeticException("Can not divide " + answer + " with " + values[0]);
                    }
                    answer /= values[0];
                } else if (values.length != 0) {
                    answer = values[0];
                    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
                        if (values[i] == 0) {
                            throw new ArithmeticException("Can not divide " + answer + " with " + values[i]);
                        }
                        answer /= values[i];
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return answer;
    }

    /**
     * Current internal state of calculator is printed
     * FORMAT:
     * "[{+/ -/"/"/*}] value1_value2 [{+/ -/"/"/*}] value1 [{+/ -/"/"/*}] value1 {...}"
     *
     * @return String of the internal state of the calculator
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("values: [");
        for (float value: values) {
            string.append(value)
                    .append(" ")
                    .append(operation)
                    .append(" ");
        }
        string.append("] answer = ").append(answer);
        return string.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the code with some test it should pass because with that code for example in executeOperations i think i didnt explain well how it is supossed to work. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielRodriguez Okay

Comment: Could you please tell me what I should modify for it to pass the test on the bottom of the question? Thank you in advance

Comment: @DanielRodriguez you will need to create a log of operations performed using single operands create a String object and log these details into that as user do .toString() you should return that object from that method and reset it when user passes two operands and when user calls execute operations too